# Obj-C, Potential leak of an object allocated on line, UIBarButtonItem alloc

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I'm getting an analyser leak, however this is the same code i'm using elsewhere without a problem. I know I'm using alloc and therefore I have to release, but I am doing this in dealloc.

What am I doing wrong ?

Header file:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, 
               UITableViewDelegate> {

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
```

Main file:

```
@synthesize addButton;
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];


    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                            target:self action:@selector(btnNavAddPressed:)];
    addButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [buttons addObject:addButton];

    [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
    [buttons release];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithCustomView:tools];

    addButton.enabled = FALSE;

- (void)dealloc {
    [addButton release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the above answers are misleading. You don't need to use a setter, it's perfectly fine to assign objects directly to iVars. You do need to release anything you alloc or retain however. The problem you have is here:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
```

This line is alloc'ing a `UIBarButtonItem` instance and setting it to the `rightBarButtonItem` property of the `navigationItem`. That means the `navigationItem` is retaining the `UIBarButtonItem` and it is responsible for that retain. You are responsible for releasing it b/c of the `alloc` and you are not. Change the code to this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools] autorelease];
```

and this leak goes away.

Comment: These types of problems are one of the most common hurdles for iOS developers. It does get easier/more natural as you gain experience. If you're using xcode 4.2 I recommend reading the docs on ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and migrating your project to that. It doesn't change the rules WRT memory management but it does allow the compiler to do almost all of the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the setter, the code should be:

```
self.addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                        target:self action:@selector(btnNavAddPressed:)] autorelease];
```

This type of problem can be avoided by using an ivar that has a different name than the property name.  This is accomplished in the `@synthesize` statement:

```
@synthesize addButton = _addButton;
```

This way any omission of `self` will result in an error message.

Here is a full implementation (except `tools` is undefined), the property addButton is handles in all places:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
@end

@implementation myViewController
@synthesize addButton = _addButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSMutableArray* buttons = [NSMutableArray array];

    self.addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                 target:self action:@selector(btnNavAddPressed:)];
    self.addButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [buttons addObject:self.addButton];

    [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools] autorelease];

    self.addButton.enabled = FALSE;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [_addButton release];
}
@end
```

Comment: Won't that give a memory leak? (these comments have got a lot harder since ARC!)

Comment: @jrturton Oops, fixed  in answer. Thanks!  Of course under ARC no autorelease is needed.

Comment: That's what I mean, it used to be really easy to spot leaks, now there's a whole extra layer. I prefer the good old days...

Comment: Make that the "Bad Old Days". :-) I find writing under ARC to be so much easier.

Comment: @CocoaFu, that doesn't seem to fix it and `@synthesize addButton = _ addButton;` gives me and error `Parse Issue: Expected ';' after @synthesize`. Also tried using self. in front of all addButton calls. Any further advice ?

Comment: Your code wrt `addButton` is fine. This is misleading advice.

Comment: There is a space after the _, make that: `@synthesize addButton = _addButton;`  My initial type, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

when you use a property and assign to it the attributes you specified determine whether retainCount is incremented if you assign to the property. In your case you specified "`retain`" which means that the setter function that handles assignment to your property will automatically increment the retain count for the object.

However when you write

```
 addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                            target:self action:@selector(btnNavAddPressed:)];
```

you are creating an opject with already retain count == 1 so when you assign it will have retain count 2. the proper way to do this is to create a temp variable and create the object, then assign the temp variable to the property thereafter releasing the temp. variable:

```
UIBarButtonItem* tmp = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                            initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                            target:self action:@selector(btnNavAddPressed:)];
self.addButton = tmp;
[tmp release];
```

of course i would recommend a more descriptive name than 'temp' as variable name.

Comment: this is misleading advice. The OP's code wrt `addButton` is fine as is. He is correctly storing the alloc'ed object directly in the iVar and releasing it in `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking advantage of the declared property but I don't see any problem with `addButton`. The leak seems more in:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
```

Just add `autorelease` and the leak will go away.

Comment: It's weird, I replicated your code and the missing autorelease is the only problem found by me and the analyzer. Clean and analyze? Or can you post the analyzer screenshot (the one with the arrows)?